# How to assemble scalars into a matrix in tensorflow?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, matrix, deep-learning, loss-function

In short, I want to assemble scalars `w_ij` into symmetric matrix `W` like so:

```
W[i, j] = w_ij
W[j, i] = w_ij
```

After struggling with this and looking up material on the internet and here on SE, I can't find a way to construct matrix `W` from `w_ij`'s, I'm lost as to how to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Elaborations and MWE are below.

---

---

### The problem

In my research I am trying to train a network that maps `source` to a scalar `w_ij`. Where the output `w_ij` is intended to represent an element `i,j` in a symmetric matrix `W`.

So, the loss for training is constructed by assembling the outputs of many identical networks (with shared weights but each seeing a different input, and  driving a different element in a matrix) into a matrix form, like so:

```
W[i, j] = w_ij
W[j, i] = w_ij
```

and then training those multiple networks on a loss of the form:

```
L2_loss(f(W) - f(True_W))
```

(Where `f()` is a function that runs `f(Y) = d' Y d` a quadratic form --- product of matrix by a fixed vector from left and right.)

I need to run gradients through this loss to each network.

---

---

### What I tried

1. A naive tensor slicing is not supported on `tensorflow`, i.e.,

   `W[i, j] = w_ij` is not supported.
2. Using `tf.scatter_update()` does not allow to run gradients through it.
3. Finally, I though I was close to a solution, I tried using `tf.Variable` for matrix `W`, like below:

   ```
    W_flat = tf.Variable(initial_value=[0] * (2 * 2), dtype='float32')
   ```

   and then assign to this `W_flat` by slicing it`W_falt[0].assign(w_ij)`, but it seems that my assignments to this variable do not work (see MWE).

---

### MWE

Bellow is a short MWE, where `W` is a 2-by-2 symmetric matrix with zero diagonal, so I only have one independent element that a network has to drive (so here I only have a single network), i.e., I would like to get `W` to have the values

```
W =   [[0, w_ij] [w_ij, 0]]
```

So I try update:

```
W_flat[1].assign(w_ij)
W_flat[2].assign(w_ij)
```

And turn it back into a matrix:

```
W = tf.reshape(W_flat, (2, 2))
```

Eventually this update does not go through, the output of `print` shows that `W` remains all zeros.

#### The code

```
import tensorflow as tf

def train():

    with tf.Graph().as_default():
        with tf.device('/cpu'):
            source = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(2, 3))
            is_training = tf.placeholder(tf.bool, shape=())

            w_ij = tf.reduce_sum(source)

            W_flat = tf.Variable(initial_value=[0] * (2 * 2), dtype='float32')

            W_flat[1].assign(w_ij)
            W_flat[2].assign(w_ij)
            tf.assign(W_flat[1], w_ij)
            tf.assign(W_flat[2], w_ij)

            W = tf.reshape(W_flat, (2, 2))

        sess = tf.Session()
        init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
        sess.run(init, {is_training: True})

        ops = {'W_flat': W_flat,
               'source' : source,
               'w_ij' : w_ij,
               'W' : W}

        for epoch in range(2):
            feed_dict = {ops['source']: [[1,1,1], [7,7,7]]}
            res_W_flat, res_wij, res_W = sess.run([ops['W_flat'], ops['w_ij'], ops['W']], feed_dict=feed_dict)
            print("epoch:" ,  epoch)
            print("W_flat:", res_W_flat)
            print("wij:", res_wij)
            print("W:", res_W)

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    train()
```

#### `print()` outputs

```
epoch: 0
W_flat: [0. 0. 0. 0.]
wij: 24.0
W: [[0. 0.]
 [0. 0.]]
epoch: 1
W_flat: [0. 0. 0. 0.]
wij: 24.0
W: [[0. 0.]
 [0. 0.]]
```

So `W` and `W_flat` is not updated by the value of `w_ij`, the value of which is 24 but `W` and `W_flat` remain zeros.

Comment: Please edit your question and avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that I found after more struggles is to use `tf.scatter_nd()` to update the matrix `W`, unlike `tf.scatter_update()`, `tf.scatter_nd()` produces tensor which does support gradients propagation from its input to its output.

So **instead** of writing

```
        W_flat = tf.Variable(initial_value=[0] * (2 * 2), dtype='float32')

        W_flat[1].assign(w_ij)
        W_flat[2].assign(w_ij)

        W = tf.reshape(W_flat, (2, 2))
```

It **worked using**:

```
        W_flat = tf.Variable(initial_value=[0] * (2 * 2), dtype='float32')
        indices = tf.constant([[1], [2]])
        shape = tf.constant([4])
        W_flat = tf.scatter_nd(indices, w_ij, shape)

        W = tf.reshape(W_flat, (2, 2))
```